# Is there a way to do rich text formatting with regexes?

Tags: linux, text-editors, regex

I'm trying to edit a large public domain text for publication. One of the things I have to do is make each paragraph's heading **bold**. Since the heading always begins with an open-paren and ends with a period, it looks like a regular expression would speed things up if I could find a rich text editor that supports it. Any ideas?

PS I'm working on linux now, so linux software would be preferred.

---

Update: As per Rob's request, I'm posting a sample of the text. It's Hebrew, but I can put in some lorum ipset if you want it.

כי השוחה והמעופף ומן הנראה שבכלל השוחה שרץ המים ובכלל המעופף שרץ העוף. (כד) ויאמר אלהים תוצא הארץ ונר. (כבר) קדם לנו טעם מאמרו בתוצא הארץ : ומאמרו נפש חיה אין טעמו שנפש חיה נוצרה מן הארץ שהרי הנוצר מן הארץ ושאר היסודות הוא חומר ואילו הנפש אפילו נפש החיה מהשפעת העולם העליון הרוחני כמבואר במדעים האמתיים לכן טעם המאמר ״תוצא הארץ חיה שיש לה נפש״ ואמנם סמך הכתוב ״נפש״ אצל ״חיה״ וחיבר שניהם במאמר תוצא הארץ [נפש חיה] לשני טעמים לפי הנראה לי אחד מהם שנפשו של החי שאינו מדבר משוקעת בחומר שקיעה רבה ומפני זה אין השארה לנפשו בעת הפרידה (מן הגוף) כמו שרמז לזה שלמה ע״ה במאמרו ונפש הבהמה ה י ר ד ת היא למטה והטעם השני שלא קדם בתחילת הבריאה חומר החי להיפרט ולצאת קודם מציאות הנפש בו אלא בבת אחת הוציא האל יתעלה מן הארץ בריות בעלי נפשות וכאילו הארץ הוציאה אותן הנפשות כמו שהוציאה את החומר שלהן: ומאמרו למינה רמז לריבוי מיני החי ופירוט האישים של כל מין ממנו בצורת מינו אשר פירט לו בוראו: ומאמרו בהמה ורמש וחיתו ארץ למינה חילוק החי של היבשה שנתהווה מן הארץ לשלושה חלקים אלה שהרי הסוג העליון של החי שהוגבל באשר הוא גוף משתמש בחושים מתחלק לשלושה חלק

Note that not all parentheses are paragraph headings. Only the ones followed by a string ending in a period, not a colon.

Comment: It might be possible to do it with editing the plain text instead of the rich text, I'll try a few things. Can you add some of the plain text to the question?

Comment: Sure. It's in Hebrew though.

Comment: If you open the text in something like `nano` or `vim` or any plain text editor, what does it look like. It'll possibly be a pain to read. That's what we'll want to edit to add control codes for bolding. The problem I always have with this kind of search and replace is regex being greedy.

Comment: Would HTML be sufficient? It's easy to replace `(כבר)` with `<strong>(כבר)</strong>`, for example.

Comment: hmmm... And then save it as an rtf? That could work. I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

There is a way... You first apply "bold" to some words in your text. Then you can open your .rtf with a non-rich editor, say notepad (or emacs), and see the "code" behind your document. It's quite human readable. If you look for the string you just bolded, you'll find how to bold any part of your text. Unfortunately I cannot really tell you what it is (except that it involved \b), as I noticed that the format changes whether you created your document with word or wordpad, or any other editor I guess, so the only way to be sure would be for you to give a sample of it (preferably with some bolded text and some not-bolded).

Creating the search and replace regexs should then be easy.